# como hago para diferenciar dos strings que se repiten un array y que devuelvan cosas distintas?

Tags: javascript

tengo un array con strings que se repiten ["tren" , "auto" , "tren", "tren"]

si aparece una vez quiero retornar "vi un tren"

si veo tres quiero retornar "vi tres trenes"  el problema es que cuando igualo al string ya no me permite devolver una condicion distinta
esto fue lo que intente

```
array = ["tren" , "auto" , "tren", "tren"]


var vista = [""]  

for ( var i = o ; i < array.lenght ; i++){
if (array[i] == "tren"){
return "vi un tren"
}

return vista
```

Comment: Pero tiene que poner el número en palabras también??

Comment: sisi me pide devolver un string si se coinciden en una o tres oportunidades

Comment: Solo 1 o 3? O pueden haber cualquier cantidad?

Answer (score 3):

Yo haría algo más idiomático.
Suponiendo que quieres contar todos los vehículos y que conoces de antemano el máximo de veces que se repite y los tipos de vehículos que hay, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let contador = {};
let vehiculos = ['tren', 'auto', 'tren', 'tren'];
let palabra = ['cero', 'un', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];
let plural = { tren: 'trenes', auto: 'autos' };
vehiculos.forEach(i => {
  contador[i] = 1 + (contador[i] || 0)
});
Object.keys(contador).forEach(i => {
  console.log("vi " + (palabra[contador[i]] || 'más de cuatro')+ ' ' + (contador[i] > 1 ? plural[i] : i));
});
```

Comment: Si pones más autos o más trenes, retorna undefined.

Comment: Ok, hice un cambio contemplando cuando haya más de 4

Comment: Ahora ya quedó bien, +1 por el buen aporte =)

Answer (score 1):

Con esta funcion podes crear otro array bidimensional que te da en en la segunda columna la cantidad de veces que se repite el elemento de la primer columna:

```
const array = ["Tren", "Auto", "Bici", "Moto", "Moto", "Tren", "Tren", "Auto","Moto","Auto","Moto", "Auto", "Auto"];
function filtrar(array){
  let arrayFiltrado = [];
  let total = 0;
  while(array.length>0){
      let m = arrayFiltrado.push([array[0], 1]);
      total = 0;
      for(let n = 0; n<array.length; n++){
          if(arrayFiltrado[m-1][0] == array[n]){
              array.splice(n,1);
              n--;
              total++;
          }  
      }
      arrayFiltrado[m-1][1] = total;
  }
  return arrayFiltrado;
}

let nuevoArray = filtrar(array);
nuevoArray.forEach(elem=>{
  console.log(`vi ${elem[1]} ${elem[0]}`);
});
```